# Does CnosDB support DELETE SQL?

Tags: cnosdb

Does CnosDB support DELETE SQL?

If supported, how is it implemented and how does the KV engine delete data?

How does it perform？

How to delete a copy of data？

Comment: the [SQL reference](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/sql.html#database) does not appear to mention `DELETE`, however [the github issue](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/issues/1594) indicates that it's coming.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that sql for delete is in the process of development, maybe soon to appear

Answer (score 0):

the [doc](https://docs.cnosdb.com/zh/latest/reference/sql.html#%E5%88%A0%E9%99%A4%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE) was publish about delete sql,maybe it will help you!